# Android app not showing on my device. No Launcher Activity Found

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am simply following the Android Developer [training guide](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/running-app.html), and I am already running into troubles on the second step.

I followed the guide (I don't even have to do anything..) and clicked on Run, selected my Galaxy S4 from the screen, and clicked okay. I get the following error

```
[2014-07-06 19:56:27 - MyFirstApp] Android Launch!
[2014-07-06 19:56:27 - MyFirstApp] adb is running normally.
[2014-07-06 19:56:27 - MyFirstApp] No Launcher activity found!
[2014-07-06 19:56:27 - MyFirstApp] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
[2014-07-06 19:56:27 - MyFirstApp] Performing sync
[2014-07-06 19:56:27 - MyFirstApp] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2014-07-06 19:56:31 - MyFirstApp] Application already deployed. No need to reinstall.
[2014-07-06 19:56:31 - MyFirstApp] \MyFirstApp\bin\MyFirstApp.apk installed on device
[2014-07-06 19:56:31 - MyFirstApp] Done!
```

I honestly have no idea what I am doing wrong, as I have absolutely no experiences with android.

The only thing that is different is in the tutorial their targetSdkVersion is 19, but I am using 21

The following is my AndroidManefiest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.myfirstapp"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to declare your activity to your Manifest.xml.

Everytime you create an activity (**blablabla class extends Activity**) you have to declare it to your Android Manifest.xml, in order to de device be able to track your App's life cicle.

What we call **Activity** is a class that provide information to host a window, the class should **extends Activity**, all of this classes must be declared on the Manifest.xml file as below:

```
<application>
    ...

    <activity
            android:name="com.yourpackage.ClassName">

    </activity>

</application>
```

Probably your activity class is called **MainActivity**, you just have to add this to your code, between `<application> </application>` tag:

```
    <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"> <!-- This is the text that will appear on your action bar -->

        <intent-filter>

            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

The `<intent-filter>` tells to android that this class is the "main entrance", the first activity that need to be loaded to your app be launched, only the first activity need the `<intent-filter>` tag, the others just need the fist example I gave.

If you are starting with Android development, I recommend you to read about [ActionBar](http://www.sitepoint.com/better-user-interfaces-android-action-bar/) and [What to do when the device is rotated](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html)

[This](http://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/index.html) and [this](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=appcompat&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=f7f7f8%2C100&secondaryColor=f7f7f8%2C100&tabColor=f7f7f8%2C100&tertiaryColor=1e130f%2C100&accentColor=f7f7f8%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) may help you in the future.

Good coding :)

Comment: Now i'm getting a "Unfortunately, MyFirstApp has stopped", which is good because this means I am getting somewhere. What am I doing wrong now ?

Thanks for all the extra information/tools by the way, I look forward to using them in the near future!

Comment: @user3277633 Please, post your MainActivity code, so I can see what is wrong.

Also, you received a Log of the error (yes, it is all of that red lines), please, copy and post it, it tells exactly what is wrong. But please, open a new question, because this question was fixed, and the new problem is not the same. Doing this will not confuse another one trying to fix the problem you openned here. Post  your new question's link here, if possible.

Comment: ah,I can only post once every 90 minutes. I will link the new question after the time limit passes. Thank you for all your help

Comment: Though I can say it probably has to do with android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" cause there is no MainActivity class under either src or gen

Comment: You're welcome! After you made a research, but you still have no answer to your problem, fell free to open a question, we are here to help. I'll be waiting for your link.

Comment: @user3277633, you have to change MainActivity to the same name of your activity class file. You have: "public class SomeName extends Activity" right? Go to "com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" and change "MainActivity" to the name you have on place of "SomeName"

Comment: correct if I am wrong, but I remember there use to be a MainActivity with the Android ADT under src. a few years back I played around with it and I do indeed remember a MainActivity. However I re-downded the newest ADT just hours ago and there doesn't seem to be a MainActivity anymore. Did google change its way of making Android apps?

Comment: Figured it out, for some reason my eclipse isn't even generating the MainActivity.xml. Time to look for a solution

Comment: No, they didn't, what is happening is you probably don't have an activity class. This article tells you a lot of important things about android development. Take a time and read it, on step 7, they teach how to create a "hello world" app. Remember: you don't need to create a virtual device to run apps, you can do the same on real devices. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Android/article.html

Comment: It depends of how you created your project. Try to create a new project and pay attention on all steps, you'll see you missed somethinig (it happens to me too, don't worry)

Comment: @user3277633, take a look at the "tutorial" session, I like vogella because they have excellent tutorials, very understandable for who want to learn Android and have doubts with Google tutorials. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/. Tuts+ is very nice too: http://code.tutsplus.com/articles/introduction-to-android-design-patterns--cms-20808

Answer (score 1):

Put the following intent-filter for your activity to be launched.

```
 <activity class=".YourActivity" android:label="your activity label">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
       </intent-filter>
 </activity>
```

> { action=android.app.action.MAIN } matches all of the activities that
>   can be used as top-level entry points into an application.
>
> { action=android.app.action.MAIN,
>   category=android.app.category.LAUNCHER } is the actual intent used by
>   the Launcher to populate its top-level list.

Also, please refer to [Intent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html)

Comment: I put the <intent> section you provided and put it underneath the <application> section, but unfortunately it still does not work

Comment: you should have one activity(which holds the view that user can see), and put the xml under that activity. Please refer to android manifest example put in the link I added. For the step 6 :"Now you can select an activity template from which to begin building your app.For this project, select BlankActivity and click Next.
"

Comment: @user3277633 What does "didn't work" mean? I suspect you are getting an error because the code given here belongs between the `<application ...>` and `</application>` tags. If that is where you put it, please update your Q with the current manifest file.